# Why we impose finite countability to be closed in $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{F}$

Tags: measure-theory

In $\sigma$-algebra, denoted as $\mathscr{F}$, one of the 3 main conditions that we impose to have a $\sigma$-algebra is the fact that for countable subsets $\{A_i, i\ge 1\}$, we need these subsets to be closed under unions:

$$
\bigcup_i{A_i}\in \mathscr{F}
$$

**Question**: However, $\mathscr{F}$ itself might have uncountable subsets, so I am confused to distinguish between the condition we just imposed for subsets to be closed under unions and the fact that $\mathscr{F}$ might have uncountable subsets? Can you please clarify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstood a thing about the $\sigma$-algebra

One condition for $\mathscr{F}$ to be a $\sigma$-algebra is that the union of contable many sets $A_i$ (where $A_i \in \mathscr{F}$ can in fact be uncountable) must be again an element of $\mathscr{F}$

For example $\mathscr{F} = P(\mathbb{R})$ is a $\sigma$ -algebra (in fact any powerset is).
And $P(\mathbb{R})$ contains elements that are uncountable.

$\mathscr{F}$ doesn't need to have countably infinite sets.
Consider a set $X = \{1,2,3\}$ and $\mathscr{F}= \{ \emptyset, X, \{1\}, \{2,3\} \}$
That's a $\sigma$ -algebra (try to check the conditions).

Comment: Thank you. So, sigma algebra must have countably infinite sets but it can have uncountable sets at the same time. So you think this is not confusing?

Comment: @Avv Not quite, I'll edit it to make it more clear. It doesn't need to have countably infinite sets.

Comment: Thanks. I see that it sigma algebra does not have to be countably infinite sets, but I was looking about the case where it's both countably infinite and countably infinite set under unions (condition 3 of sigma algebra).

Comment: Mario, I forgot to ask you, is it the case that all measurable subsets of sigma algebra has to be also subsets of sample space?

Comment: @Avv Yes, exactly. It's always the case that $\sigma$ algebra $\mathscr{F} \subseteq P(X)$ for a defined set $X$. So all elements of $\mathscr{F}$ are subsets of $X$.